# Keyboard not working during boot

Tags: mac, keyboard, startup, unix

My Mac keyboard is not working during EFI startup, so I can’t press option to select the boot device. I am dual booting Archlinux, so my EFI binary is from systemd-boot. I configured timeout in loader.conf, it shows the menu but I can’t even change the selection. Fortunately it boots Arch successfully, so I can change anything from inside.

**How can I use my Mac keyboard during EFI startup?**

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different! :) Can I ask you to please [edit](https://apple.stackexchange.com/posts/304360/edit) your question to provide some additional details. For example, we don't know whether you're using a laptop (and therefore a built-in keyboard) or an external keyboard. If it's external, is it an Apple keyboard or generic keyboard? Bluetooth or USB? Also, what exact model of Mac and what version of macOS is installed?